# Should I pass an std::vector or a fixed number of arguments?

Tags: c++, performance, utf-8, arguments, stdvector

I am wringing a class method that will convert a [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) character into its representative Unicode code point. My prototype candidates are the ones below:

```
static uint32_t Utf8ToWStr( uint8_t Byte1,        uint8_t Byte2 = 0x00,
                            uint8_t Byte3 = 0x00, uint8_t Byte4 = 0x00,
                            uint8_t Byte5 = 0x00, uint8_t Byte6 = 0x00);

static uint32_t Utf8ToWStr(const std::vector<uint8_t> & Bytes);
```

In my applications;
`Byte1` will be the only non-zero byte approximately 90% of the time.
`Byte1` and `Byte2` will be the only non-zero bytes approximately 9% of the time.
`Byte1`, `Byte2` and `Byte3` will be the only non-zero byte less than 1% of the time.
`Byte4`, `Byte5` and `Byte6` will almost always be zero.

Which prototype should I prefer for speed?

Comment: Why not to measure the performance? You have already 2 functions, you know the use-case, so I think the best you can do is just measure it experimentally

Comment: This interface looks cumbersome. Why not just take a `uint8_t *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably neither.

Think of the code calling this function -- they will likely have to jump through massive hoops to use it:

```
uint8_t c1 = *cursor++;
uint8_t c2 = 0;
uint8_t c3 = 0;
uint8_t c4 = 0;
uint8_t c5 = 0;
uint8_t c6 = 0;
if(c1 >= 0x80)
    c2 = *cursor++;
if(c1 >= 0xc0)
    c3 = *cursor++;
if(c1 >= 0xe0)
    c4 = *cursor++;
if(c1 >= 0xf0)
    c5 = *cursor++;
if(c1 >= 0xf8)
    c6 = *cursor++;
uint32_t wch = Utf8ToWStr(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6);
```

I sincerely doubt this interface is useful.

My normal interface for conversion routines is

```
bool utf8_to_wchar(uint8_t const *&cursor, uint8_t const *end, uint32_t &result);
```

The return value is used to convey errors (for example, how would your function react to the parameters `(0x81, 0x00)`?

Last but not least, you might want to have a mode that specifies whether denormalized UTF-8 should give an error -- from a security POV it is a good idea to disallow encoding `U+003F` as `0x80 0x3f`.

Comment: Just to second the reference to iterator, end iterator approach.  It's what I use as well.  (On the other hand, I use exceptions to signal errors, so I can return the `uint32_t` directly.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use

```
// if you want it as simple as possible
typedef uint8_t data_t[6];
```

or

```
// if you like C++11
typedef std::array<uint8_t, 6> data_t;
```

or

```
// if it should be extensible
typedef struct { uint8_t data[6]; } data_t;
```

to point out the fixed length nature of the input data at compile time. This way it saves you a lot of typing actually calling the function.

Using a variable length vector would to me somehow suggest there could be more or less or empty data.

Answer (score 1):

std::vector is probably slower, because it stores those bytes to heap and allocates memory for them.

You could also just pass a pointer to byte array, or use std::array if using C++11.